# webRTC is not reconnecting after internet dropout on Chrome mobile

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc, mobile-chrome

I have a webRTC video which is working as expected between Chrome on PC and Chrome on mobile but if the internet connection is disrupted on the mobile it will not resume the webRTC video when it is back online, however it will resume correctly if it is the Chrome on PC that has the internet disrupted.

It is the same implementation used regardless of device or browser and chrome mobile seems to support webRTC the same as desktop (https://caniuse.com/?search=webrtc), why might it be failing on mobile chrome?

I have the below 'oniceconnectionstatechange' function:

```
 pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = event => {
     if (pc.iceConnectionState === 'failed') {
       pc.restartIce()
     }
  }
```

Comment: Experienced some kind of this while working on native webrtc app,  it happenned in major time when  switching between mobile network and wifi network (that happen automatically if wifi drop). In this case i was  fully renegotiating the peer to be able to restart the media.
I suppose that the annnounce ip change in this case and a restart can't be effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are seeing the different behaviors because of your [NAT Mappings](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#nat-mapping). It could be something else, but with the details we have that is my first guess.

When the connection is disrupted on desktop (and then returns) you are keeping your NAT Mapping. When the connection is disrupted on mobile maybe you are getting a new one. You could confirm the behavior yourself by sending UDP packets from your phone and printing out the src details on a world routable server.

The proper way to reconnect a peer is to do an [ICE Restart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/restartIce). That ensures that even if your network path changes you will reconnect.

Comment: I already have restartIce() in my oniceconnectionstatechange function (updated in question) is it not setup correctly?

Comment: I am not sure. Can you share some code? Do you exchange all ICE Candidates and make another answer from the remote peer?